# Which pattern is used to converted MAR, APR, JUN, etc

Tags: java, android, date

Im trying to parse date  31-MAR-22 16:49 with this method, but it doesn't works

it throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30-MAR-22 16:49' could not be parsed at index 3`

I  passed hard coded date "30-Mar-22 16:49" instead of "30-MAR-22 16:49" diff is "Mar" and it worked. I have to know which pattern is used to convert MAR

```
 getConvertedDates(date: String?): String {
    val format = "MMM d"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm")
    val parsedDate = formatter.parse(date)
    val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)
    return displayFormatter.format(parsedDate).toString()
}
```

Comment: `Y` is day of week which is dangerous (it almost does what you want, but not quite). You want `u`. However, I doubt that's what you meant by 'doesn't works'. You need to supply a bit more detail. Do you get compiler errors? runtime errors? A result you did not expect or want? Paste the errors, or if no errors, the result you got vs. the result you want.

Comment: Im getting null,  I have date  in this format -> 31-MAR-22 16:49 and i want to convert it like that -> Mar 31

Comment: `"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm"` - the `y` has to be lower case.

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30-MAR-22 16:49' could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: I think problem is -> AR . no ? MMM = Mar are not ?

Comment: not works, same exception

Comment: I passed hard coded date  "30-Mar-22 16:49" instead of "30-MAR-22 16:49" diff is "Mar" and it worked. I have to know which pattern is used to convert MAR

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry, had not noticed your month is in all upper case. You need `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("dd-MMM-uu HH:mm").toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)`. Yes, it’s a bit complicated to specify that case should be ignored in parsing.

Comment: [Full working code online here](https://ideone.com/MbsTT9)

Comment: thanks very much, it worked and I'll use it , but I think I cant pass review with that :D lets see, thank u one more time